# XNA 4.0 Custom Vertex Declaration

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently trying to make a custom vertex declaration.

One where a position, color and integer is passed to the Effect. I am having issues determining what enum for VertexElementUsage would be used for passing an integer and how does one determine the offset when declaring VertexElements as well?

```
public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
{
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
    new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),
    new VertexElement(?, VertexElementFormat.Byte4, ?, 0)
};
```

(Note the ? in the last VertexElement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will be the size of Vector2 + the size of the color.
Basically think of it this way,
in a normal array, there are only one type of objects, so it's known how much to jump to get to the next item.
This here is different, as they all have different sizes.
Using sizeof() is just fine, so it'll be like:

```
public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
{
    new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(Vector3), VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),
    new VertexElement(sizeof(Vector3)+sizeof(Color), VertexElementFormat.Byte4, ?, 0)
};
```

or similar.

Otherwise you can find the size of a color object and add it to the size of the Vector3 object (and that will be the offset).

Comment: And what about the VertexElementUsage?

Comment: Anything you want. Inside your HLSL effect, the data can be accessed through whatever you say is the usage.

Comment: For example VertexElementUsage.Position means you can get the data contained there inside your effect through "POSITION0" (or similar, I don't work with HLSL much, but that's the whole point of the usage part)

Comment: Well, sizeof is not going to work for me: "'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context (consider using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)"

Comment: @lampak First of all, `sizeof()` works perfectly fine with Vector3 as can be seen by the OP accepting the answer (it works). Secondly, do note this thread is 2 months old. `Marshal.SizeOf()` IS a good .NET solution, but it is somewhat slower. If a problem does eventually happen with `sizeof()`, or if the OP said sizeof() had a problem I would recommend that. `sizeof()` usage is fine in most cases though, much faster and older - tested by time. `sizeof()` exited back in C and still works in a similar way. It simply calculates the size of each of Vector3 components to get the size of that obj.